# ¿Cómo se dice en español al número seguido de (21x6) = 126 ceros? (equivalencia de término con el inglés)

Tags: solicitud-de-término, números, matemáticas

En inglés en algunos sitios usan palabras como *unvigintillion* para el número seguido de 63 ceros (21x3) o *unquadragintillion* para el número seguido de 123 ceros (41x3).

Nosotros, a diferencia de ellos, cuando pasamos de millón a billón o trillón o cuatrillón agregamos **6** ceros (ellos agregan **3**), (un trillion en inglés es un billón en español) por lo que pedir la traducción de *unvigintillion* no sería correcta para referirse a un número con 120 ceros sino que se debería pedir la traducción de *unquadragintillion* para el equivalente en ceros en español.

Por lo tanto mi pregunta es: ¿qué palabra se debería usar en español para un número con 126 ceros (21x6)? (asumiendo que si en inglés existe tal palabra, en español podría haber una).

Comment: La verdad, para esos números usa notación científica: 1+E126. El lenguaje sirve para comunicarse, y nadie va a entender "unvigintillion" sin tener que buscarlo aquí (por no hablar del riesgo de confusión entre la escala corta y la larga).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta diferencia en la terminología se debe al uso de [las escalas numéricas larga y corta](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalas_num%C3%A9ricas_larga_y_corta):

[image]

| número | cantidad de ceros | escala corta | escala larga |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10¹²⁶ | 126 = 42*3 = 21*6 | unquadragintillion | unvigintillion |

Así en español la palabra sería **unvigintillón**, pero no hay ninguna fuente 'oficial' que cuente los nombres de los números más allá de 10<sup>30</sup>.

- https://www.grobauer.at/es_eur/zahlnamen.php
- http://nummolt.blogspot.com/2014/03/letter-toraequintillioncentilliontxt.html
- [http://www.aolivella.cat/Rafanell/Apunts/nou/Logica Booleana Basico/Logica Booleana Basico WP.doc](http://www.aolivella.cat/Rafanell/Apunts/nou/Logica%20Booleana%20Basico/Logica%20Booleana%20Basico%20WP.doc)